# Mapping array values from web method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, vb.net

I am trying to map array values which are returned by a webmethod into the array declared in javascript. the webmethod array is two dimensional. I have worked with single dimensional array mapping. but i have tried the following code for 2D, but its not working. please let me get some help.

webmethod:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod()> _
Public Shared Function twoDarr(ByVal para() As Object, ByVal spname As String) As Object(,)
    Dim dsrt As New DataSet, dbacc As New dataaccess, arr(0, 0) As Object
    dsrt = dbacc.retds1(spname, conn, para)
    ReDim arr(dsrt.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1, dsrt.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1)
    For i As Integer = 0 To dsrt.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To dsrt.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            arr(i, j) = dsrt.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j)
        Next
    Next
    Return arr
End Function
```

Javascript:

```
    PageMethods.twoDarr(para,"sp_rlplsett",success,error);
    function success(res)
    {
        for(i=0;i<res.length-1:i++)
        {
        dsrp[i]=new Array(res[i].length);
        for(j=0;j<res[i].length-1;j++)
        {
        dsrp[i][j]=res[i][j];
        }
        }
    }
```

note:get me with the replacement of function Success() block.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

web method:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod()> _
Public Shared Function twoDarr(ByVal para() As Object, ByVal spname As String) As String(,)
    Dim dsrt As New DataSet, dbacc As New dataaccess, arr(0, 0) As String
    dsrt = dbacc.retds1(spname, conn, para)
    ReDim arr(dsrt.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1, dsrt.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1)
    Dim len As Integer = arr.Length
    For i As Integer = 0 To dsrt.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To dsrt.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            arr(i, j) = dsrt.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j)
        Next
    Next
    Return arr
End Function
```

Javascript:

```
var dsrp =[];var ind;var col='your col value';var i;var j;
for (i=0;i<2;i++)
{
var data2=[];
for (j=0;j<col;j++)
{
data2.push(ress[ind]);
ind++;
}
dsrp1.push(data2);
}
```